# TMC2130 Stepper Motor on Raspberry Pi. SPI issue?

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

For the last few days I've been struggling to get a NEMA17 (1.5 rated current) stepper motor to function with TMC2120 driver (vref = 1.0) and I'm all out of options now to try, so I'm here looking for some help.

I think it may be SPI related due to me not getting back expected results on statuses, but all looks fine to me using PISCOPE but maybe someone here can confirm or correct any wrongs?

TMC2130 Datasheet - https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC2130_datasheet.pdf
Raspberry PI model B. v1.1

Here's what I'm trying and what I'm expecting:

- I'm using spidev in python to send the 5 bytes (40 bits) to get the general config (GCONF, page 25 datasheet) - Sending 00000000 0000000 00000000 000000000 00000000 (40 zeros)
- I get the response of 01111000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 back, of which bits 39 to 32 (01111000) should be the SPI_STATUS (page 22 datasheet) meaning 'driver_error' was set, 'sg2' was set, and 'standstill detected'.
- As per the datasheet I then read GSTAT with 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 to clear it but get the response 01111000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 which would tell me there's no error and nothing was reset? Which make no sense to me and makes me think something is incorrect here.

The motor has turned previously after trying various things, but it wasn't in time with the step pulse for some reason. The only large and repeatable movement seemed to happen on GPOIO.cleanup() rather than during the script itself where post cleanup() the STEP/DIR pins were pulsing slightly. I can also hear the motor turn on and cause resistance but nothing more most of the time.

I have tried 5v and 3.3v, different motor, different driver so neither of those are the issue I assume. I've tried the Initialisation Example on (page 84) and the stepping the motor with STEP GPIO on/offs but nothing happens. Am I doing something very wrong here, because it feels like it.

I've tested the connections for continuity to check none of my solder is causing a connection to any unwanted pins, but that's the extend of my checking knowledge. If I can try anything else then let me know. I have a multimeter, but no oscilloscope (apart from software based PISCOPE)

Code used:

```
#!/home/pi/.local/bin
import spidev
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys

CLK = 23 
MISO = 21 
MOSI = 19
CS = 24
ENABLE = 29
STEP = 37
DIR = 31

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(STEP, GPIO.OUT, initial=1)
GPIO.setup(DIR, GPIO.OUT, initial=1)
GPIO.setup(CS, GPIO.OUT, initial=1)

spi = spidev.SpiDev()

WRITE_FLAG = 0x80 #write flag
READ_FLAG =  0x00 #read flag
REG_GCONF = 0x00
REG_GSTAT = 0x01
REG_IHOLD_IRUN = 0x10
REG_TPOWER_DOWN = 0x11
REG_TPWMTHRS = 0x13
REG_PWN_CONF = 0x70
REG_CHOPCONF = 0x6C
REG_COOLCONF = 0x6D
REG_DCCTRL = 0x6E
REG_DRVSTATUS = 0x6F
REG_MSCNT = 0x06A
REG_PWM_SCALE = 0x71

def bytelist_to_bin(byte_list):
    returning_list = []
    for byte in byte_list:
        binary = "{:0>8b}".format(byte)
        returning_list.append(binary)
    full_bin = ''.join(returning_list)
    return full_bin

def get_spi_status(first_byte):
    print("SPI status...", first_byte)
    error_list = []
    if first_byte[7] == 1:
        error_list.append("reset_flag was set")
    if first_byte[6]:
        error_list.append("driver_error was set")
        gstat_errors = tmc_write([READ_FLAG + REG_GSTAT, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00], False)
        print("GSTAT resp:", bytelist_to_bin(gstat_errors))
    if first_byte[5]:
        error_list.append("sg2 was set")
    if first_byte[4]:
        error_list.append("standstill detected")

    if len(error_list) > 0:
        print(error_list)

def check_for_error(bin_resp):
    # total_len = 40
    print("Response bin:", bin_resp)
    spi_status = bin_resp[0:8]
    get_spi_status(spi_status)

def tmc_write(byte_list, check_errors=True):
    print("Making call to:", hex(byte_list[0]))
    print("Write bytes:", bytelist_to_bin(byte_list))
    reply = spi.xfer2(byte_list)
    print("rep", reply)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    if check_errors: 
        print("Checking errors..")
        check_for_error(bytelist_to_bin(reply))

    return reply

def setup():
    print("Setup")
    spi.open(0, 0)
    spi.lsbfirst = False
    spi.max_speed_hz = 7629 # Seems to work fine
    modes = [0]

    for mode in modes:
        print("Running mode:", mode)
        spi.mode = mode

        # tmc_write([WRITE_FLAG + REG_CHOPCONF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xC0]) # Reset the TOFF to 0 to re-enable driver if needed

        delay = 1 / 10
        GPIO.output(DIR, 1)
        time.sleep(delay)
        tmc_write([READ_FLAG + REG_GCONF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])

        for i in range(20):
            print("range:", i)
            GPIO.output(STEP, 0)
            time.sleep(delay)
            GPIO.output(STEP, 1)
            time.sleep(delay)

    print("Sleep...")
    time.sleep(5)

def cleanup():
    print("Cleanup...")
    GPIO.cleanup()
    spi.close()

time.sleep(2)
print("Starting..")

setup()
cleanup()
```

SPI PISCOPE view:

8/CE0 is my CS pin.
26 is step
6 is dir, but the screenshot is before any step on/offs.

[image]

UPDATE 1:

I've now re-wired my prototype board to check if there were any issues there but there's no change. I've got the SPI response working (see comments), and this is now giving me a s2ga (short to ground) DRV_STATUS error (page 38 datasheet) " Short to GND detected on phase A or B. The driver becomes disabled. The flags stay active, until the driver is disabled by software (TOFF=0) or by the ENN input." I dont know how to find and resolve this though?

Comment: 1. I think your SPI hardware and software looks more or less OK. 2. But why frequency set so low? 3. Have you ever tried to use a square wave sig gen to move the motor?

Comment: 4. Of course you also need to use jumper wires to manually config the driver first.

Comment: 1. thanks, it's nice to know that matches what I think it should be. 2. The frequency is low because that's all that seemed to get the correct output on PISCOPE, but I think that might be an issue with Piscope than anything else from what I've read recently. 3. I haven't tried this no, I presume it's software based so I'll give it a google to try today (feel free to point me to any scripts/resources on it if you have any handy)

Comment: Ha, when I started playing with my tmc2209 a while ago, I skimmed the data sheet and used jumper wires to config, and a sig gen to send the steps, and the motor started moving happily.

Comment: You might like to go to Rpi SE and search tmc2209 to find my tldr answer!

Comment: Two more things.  (1) You seem to forget to initialize the ENABLE pin. (2) When you clean up GPIO, all GPIO output pins would automatically return to INPUT mode.  This is a trap to many newbies.

Comment: Thanks. I've been tying the ENABLE pin to ground which is 0 I believe? The SPI screengrab above doesn't seem to say that though so I'll double check. I have tried via a GPIO pin too though. The response issue I was having looks like it's due to it being sent on the next request for reads, so I'm playing with that now to check outputs and errors now I can.

Comment: Yes, I am reading the tmc2130 datasheet and now understand why you missed the "pin operation mode".  In tmc2209 datasheet, this "***standalone or pin mode***" is clearly explained. (4) Ref: TMC2130 DATASHEET (Rev. 1.10 / 2018-MAY-09) Page 5 
https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC2130_datasheet.pdf

Section 1 - Principles of Operation

THE TMC2130 OFFERS THREE BASIC MODES OF OPERATION: / to continue, ...

Comment: (1) In Step/Direction Driver Mode, the TMC2130 is the microstep sequencer and power driver between a motion controller and a two phase stepper motor. Configuration of the TMC2130 is done via SPI. 

(2) ***In Standalone Mode, the TMC2130 can be configured using pins. In this mode of operation CPU interaction is not necessary, ...***

(3) The third mode of operation is the SPI Driver Mode, ...

Comment: Perhaps what is confusing is that, in standalone/pin mode, no cpu/mpu is necessary, ***but you do need a square wave pulse/PWM/(Step) signal generator to send the step signal.***

Comment: (1) My enable pin function is something like this: def tmcStartMotor(enblPin): 
    setGpOutPinLow(enblPin)
    return
(2) This is a complete listing of my still buggy Pico MicroPython program:
https://penzu.com/p/6f3b4f94.

Comment: I've tried with the enable pin and still no luck. Running DRV_STATUS after each step is showing s2ga as 1 though? Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Looking at my chip it's a SPI version so I should be able to use operation mode 1 or 3 in the datasheet I presume. Another thing to add it that when I run my stepping script, sometimes it ends with the motor being in an active state (hard to move) and sometimes it's free to rotate. It seems strange that it'd be doing that to me, but I dont know how to debug the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133206/discussion-between-john-and-tlfong01).